# How to force an app to open at the root storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

How would I go about forcing an app to start at my login screen(rootViewController) each time the app is started?
Currently it opens at whichever view controller I left it at, which I think is what is meant to happen.

P.S. sorry new to stackoverflow and iOS development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using storyboards, you could use unwind segues:

1. Create an unwind IBAction method in your root view controller like so:

   ```
   - (IBAction)unwindToLogin:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
   {
       // Do something after unwinding
   }
   ```

   Remember to declare the method in the header file of the root view controller class so IB can find it.

   ```
   - (IBAction)unwindToLogin:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
   ```
2. For all storyboard scenes connected by segues (directly or indirectly) to the root view controller's scene, do the following:

   - Use the storyboard's document outline to connect the view controller to the "Exit" segue by holding down the ctrl key, clicking on the view controller and dragging and dropping on the green "Exit" segue placeholder. Select the "unwindToLogin:" selector when prompted.

     [image: Connecting unwind segue]
   - Set the identifier of the manual unwind segue (just created):

     [image: Select the new unwind segue]

     [image: Set identifier of unwind segue]
   - In the view controller for that scene, listen for the "application did become active" notification (which will be posted whenever the app enters the foreground) like so:

     ```
     - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
     {
         [super viewWillAppear:animated];

         // Do other viewWillAppear stuff...

         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                  selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive)
                                                      name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
     }
     ```

     When the notification is received, perform the unwind segue (effectively displaying the login screen again to the user):

     ```
     - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive
     {
         //Perform unwind segue
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwind" sender:self];
     }
     ```

     Remember to remove the observation when we aren't the presenting view controller anymore:

     ```
     - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
     {
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                         name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                                       object:nil];

         // Do other viewWillDisappear stuff...

         [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
     }
     ```

That's it. Now whenever the user opens the app, the currently presenting view controller will be dismissed and the root view controller (which in this case is a login view controller) will be presented again.

If you don't want to unwind the segues all the way back to the root view controller (effectively logging the user out), you could preserve the current state by presenting a modal login view controller on top of the currently presenting controller when the notification is received. To do this, replace the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method with:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive
{
    // Where "LoginViewController" is your UIViewController that manages your user login.
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

*Note that the above solution assumes the use of ARC and iOS6.x*

Comment: No problem. One last thought... you might want to unwind on receipt of `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` instead of `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`. That way, there is no chance of the user seeing the view change quickly before their eyes when they reopen the app.

Comment: Yes this works nicely, but if we have a modals presented then they are still attached to the screen and they should be dismissed manually.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. Are you sure your modally presented view controller is in the segue chain attached to the root view controller?

Answer (score 1):

Simple In AppDelegate's applicationDidBecomeActive just write

```
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
[nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the view controller in the Storyboard is selected and select 'Is Initial View Controller':

[image]

Comment: Oh I mean more like a login screen or loading screen. Something that pops up every time I open the app

Comment: [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:yourloginController animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

> Currently it opens at whichever view controller I left it at

It seems you want to see your controller after minimization and restore you app, not after loading at first time. I understood correctly?
In this case behavior you described is normal.